# Qt Model-View custom delegate not working

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, model-view

I'm studying model-view programming in Qt. I'm trying to implement a custom list model with a custom delegate. It's a simple list widget with with in every row a widget with a few of label.

The widget show nothing. Debugging I noticed the delegates method are never called, so of course I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what it is.

**userinfo.h**

```
#ifndef USERINFO_H
#define USERINFO_H

#include <QString>
#include <QTime>
#include <QImage>

class UserInfo
{
public:
   UserInfo();
   UserInfo(const UserInfo&);
   ~UserInfo();

   QString getTitle() const;
   QString getSubtitle() const;
   QTime getTime() const;
   QImage getAvatar() const;

   void setTitle(const QString& value);
   void setSubtitle(const QString& value);
   void setTime(const QTime& value);
   void setAvatar(const QImage& value);

private:
   UserInfo(const QString& title);
   UserInfo(const QString& title, const QString& subtitle, const QTime& time, const QImage& icon);

   QString title;
   QString subtitle;
   QTime time;
   QImage avatar;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(UserInfo)

#endif // USERINFO_H
```

**userinfo.cpp**

```
#include "userinfo.h"

static const int _regUserInfo = qRegisterMetaType<UserInfo>("UserInfo");

UserInfo::UserInfo()
   : UserInfo("User")
{
}

UserInfo::UserInfo(const QString& title)
   : UserInfo(title, "Comment", QTime(0,0,0,0), QImage(":/resources/icon.png"))
{
}

UserInfo::UserInfo(const QString& title, const QString& subtitle, const QTime& time, const QImage& icon) :
   title(title),
   subtitle(subtitle),
   time(time),
   avatar(icon)
{
}

QImage UserInfo::getAvatar() const
{
    return avatar;
}

void UserInfo::setAvatar(const QImage& value)
{
    avatar = value;
}

QTime UserInfo::getTime() const
{
    return time;
}

void UserInfo::setTime(const QTime& value)
{
    time = value;
}

QString UserInfo::getSubtitle() const
{
    return subtitle;
}

void UserInfo::setSubtitle(const QString& value)
{
    subtitle = value;
}

QString UserInfo::getTitle() const
{
    return title;
}

void UserInfo::setTitle(const QString& value)
{
    title = value;
}

UserInfo::UserInfo(const UserInfo&) = default;
UserInfo::~UserInfo() = default;
```

**userlistmodel.h**

```
#ifndef USERMODEL_H
#define USERMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include "userinfo.h"

class UserListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
   UserListModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);

   int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const;
   QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const;

   bool setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role);
   QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                       int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

   bool insertRows(int position, int row, const QModelIndex& parent=QModelIndex());

private:
   QList<UserInfo> users;
};

#endif // USERMODEL_H
```

**userlistmodel.cpp**

```
#include "userlistmodel.h"
#include <QDebug>

UserListModel::UserListModel(QObject* parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

int UserListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
   Q_UNUSED(parent)

   return users.size();
}

QVariant UserListModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
   if (!index.isValid())
       return QVariant();

   if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
       return QVariant();

   if (index.row() >= users.size())
       return QVariant();

   return QVariant::fromValue<UserInfo>(users.at(index.row()));
}

bool UserListModel::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role)
{
   qDebug() << index.isValid();
   qDebug() << (role == Qt::EditRole) ;
   qDebug() <<value.canConvert<UserInfo>();
   if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole && value.canConvert<UserInfo>()) {

       users.replace(index.row(), value.value<UserInfo>());
       emit dataChanged(index, index);
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}

QVariant UserListModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{

   if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
      return QVariant();

   if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
      return QString("Column %1").arg(section);
   else
      return QString("Row %1").arg(section);

}

bool UserListModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
   beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position+rows-1);

   for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
       users.insert(position, UserInfo());
   }

   endInsertRows();
   return true;
}
```

**userentrywidget.h**

```
#ifndef USERENTRYWIDGET_H
#define USERENTRYWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include "userinfo.h"

class UserEntryWidget : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit UserEntryWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

   void setUserInfo(const UserInfo& user);

private:
   QLabel *avatar, *title, *subtitle, *time;
};

#endif // USERENTRYWIDGET_H
```

**userentrywidget.cpp**

```
#include "userentrywidget.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>

UserEntryWidget::UserEntryWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
   avatar = new QLabel();
   title = new QLabel("title");
   subtitle = new QLabel("subtitle");
   time = new QLabel("00:00");

   auto layout = new QHBoxLayout();
   layout->addWidget(avatar);

   auto centralColumn = new QVBoxLayout();
   centralColumn->addWidget(title);
   centralColumn->addWidget(subtitle);
   layout->addItem(centralColumn);

   layout->addWidget(time);

   this->setLayout(layout);
}

void UserEntryWidget::setUserInfo(const UserInfo& user)
{
   avatar->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(user.getAvatar()));
   title->setText(user.getTitle());
   subtitle->setText(user.getSubtitle());
   time->setText(user.getTime().toString("hh:mm"));
}
```

**useritemdelegate.h**

```
#ifndef USERITEMDELEGATE_H
#define USERITEMDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include "userentrywidget.h"

class UserItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
   UserItemDelegate(QObject* parent = nullptr);

   QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const;
   void setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index) const;
};

#endif // USERITEMDELEGATE_H
```

**useritemdelegate.cpp**

```
#include "useritemdelegate.h"

UserItemDelegate::UserItemDelegate(QObject* parent) : QStyledItemDelegate (parent)
{
}

QWidget* UserItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
   if (index.data().canConvert<UserInfo>()) {
      UserInfo user = qvariant_cast<UserInfo>(index.data());
      auto editor = new UserEntryWidget(parent);
      editor->setUserInfo(user);

      return editor;
   } else {
      return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
   }
}

void UserItemDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
   if (index.data().canConvert<UserInfo>()) {
      UserInfo user = qvariant_cast<UserInfo>(index.data());
      UserEntryWidget* userEditor = qobject_cast<UserEntryWidget*>(editor);
      userEditor->setUserInfo(user);

   } else {
      QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor, index);
   }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QListView>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>
#include "userentrywidget.h"
#include "useritemdelegate.h"
#include "userlistmodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   qRegisterMetaType<UserInfo>("UserInfo");
   qDebug() << QMetaType::type("UserInfo");

   auto lm = new UserListModel();
   lm->insertRows(0, 5);

   auto widget = new QListView();
   widget->setModel(lm);
   widget->setItemDelegate(new UserItemDelegate());
   widget->resize(500, 300);
   widget->show();

   return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't createEditor and setEditorData be virtual?

Comment: @TonyJ they are. it just miss an `override`. You don't have to specify `virtual` when reimplementing a virtual function

Comment: @Moia One of the problems is that createEditor is only used when the user wants to edit the items, in your case your items are not editable since in the flags you have not enabled it, on the other hand your editor UserEntryWidget is not an editor because they are QLabels, by default it will be to show the data of the role Qt::DisplayRole and a QString is expected and clearly a UserInfo is not.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, how I suppose to change in the delegate? I'm still learning, I'm not full aware of everything I'm doing with those

Comment: @Moia  you have to overwrite the delegate's paint method, I recommend you read: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm well aware of that example, yet I have no idea of how write the paint event, since that draw directly the polyline and I already have a widget which should paint itself. What is not clear to me in all the example is what is mandatory and what is done for that specific example

Comment: if you do not want to write the paint method then you must open the editor permanently for it use: `widget->openPersistentEditor(lm->index (i, 0));` where i is the row you want to open the editor.

Comment: It also overwrites the sizeHint() of the delegate by returning the size of the widget

Comment: @eyllanesc `widget->openPersistentEditor(lm->index (i, 0));` doesn't do nothing. If you can make an answer with a paint() example I'm going to mark that as accepted.

Comment: @Moia This is my test code, run it https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/52483937

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180685/discussion-between-moia-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: _The widget show nothing_ because `UserItemDelegate` inherits `QStyledItemDelegate` and the implementation of [QStyledItemDelegate::paint](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qstyleditemdelegate.cpp.html#_ZNK19QStyledItemDelegate15initStyleOptionEP20QStyleOptionViewItemRK11QModelIndex) expects a valid and non-null `Qt::DisplayRole`, but you never set one.

Comment: @scopchanov could you provide an example of the paint() implementation?